# Blue electrical boxes extend beyond finished ceiling

Tags: lighting, ceiling

My electrician installed the blue light boxes at an angle that  does not match my ceiling and they also extend 1/4 to 1/2 inch below the finished ceiling. we planned on 4 inch led gimbal lights to compensate for the angled ceiling.  If we trim down the blue box flush the light will no longer fit. The electrician has found a flush led to fit but no gimbal. anyone have an idea that will let me keep a gimbal? thanks k

Comment: My idea is to tell the electrician he doesn't get paid until he does a decent job...

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply accept the slight protrusion of the boxes?

Comment: Just put some trim around the exposed edge, or just paint the edge to match the ceiling. Are the boxes just nailed into the ceiling joists or are they on metal stretch bars? Are the boxes round or rectangular?

Comment: A photo of the light base would really help. I've dealt with a number of odd ceiling light situations, but I'm not really sure what we're talking about here.

Comment: Can't accept the protrusion, it hangs down up to a 1/2 inch. So 1/2 inch (depth) of blue plastic exposed , they are on the metal stretch bars and we have used spray foam insulation.

Comment: /var/folders/sg/370jh85x6xd1q8wzhgc045680000gn/T/com.apple.iChat/Messages/Transfers/IMG_1824.jpg

Comment: not sure how to add a photo

Comment: boxes are 3 in round new build boxes

Comment: See the very last section of this help page for how to format links to an image. As a new user you will have to upload it somewhere public first and then link to it. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/formatting